# QGraphicsView is not getting fit into window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am having QGraphicsView, which has multiple QGraphicsItem's. When my view loads first time and gets visible on screen, it can not be fit fully in the screen. Around 80% of view gets visible. Then I need to use scrolling to see the remaining 20% of the view.

> How my whole view will get visible at the time of loading ?

I tried following way :
(After adding all the items into view )

```
QRectF a = scene->sceneRect();      
 view->ensureVisible(a,200,200);
```

But still my view is 80% visible.

Comment: Note that [`QGraphicsView::ensureVisible`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#ensureVisible) only tries to scroll to make the requested rec visible. You should either zoom out the `QGraphicsView` or resize your window itself to make enough space for the full scene.

Comment: @m7913d I tried to zoom out 2 times and design gets fit perfectly into the window. But another design has more height so 2 times of zoom out does not fit that design perfectly in the window.

Comment: @m7913d I tried this also. 
       `QRectF a = scene->sceneRect();`
       `view->setFixedSize(a.width(),a.height());`   But for some view( whose height is more) window height beocmes more such that I can not choose `QDockWidgets` tab.   I am showing view through `QDockWidget` who has multiple tab for multiple view.

Comment: @m7913d     Is this possible ?   `Ultimately I dont want scroll bar in my initial view. So after adding all the items in the view, if there is a scroll bar, then I should do zoom-out my view. If still there is a a scroll bar, then again zoom-out till my view has a no scroll bar.`

Comment: Just try to calculate the correct horizontal/vertical scale factor, based on the available width/height and the scene width/height.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, turn off the scroll bars, it can be achived by:

```
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

called on `QGraphicsView` instance.

If you have all added items to the scene, use sceneRect to get bouding rect of all added items to the scene, and the geometry of the view - drawable widget of the view is accessed by `viewport()` method.

When you have the scene geometry and the view geometry you can compute the scale factor which can be applied to the view by `QGraphicsView::scale()` method.

The algo to compute the scale factor (**one scale factor** for both vertical and horizontal axis because we don't want to stretch content of view in some axis) is as follows:

```
if (sceneWidth > viewWidth)
    s = viewWidth / sceneWidth
    // check if scene scaled by scale fit in vertical
    if (s * sceneHeight > viewHeight)
        s = viewHeight / sceneHeight
// else if condition for checking sceneHeight > viewHeight
view->scale(s,s)
```

Minimal code:

```
class TRect : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    TRect(QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr) : QGraphicsItem(parent) {}
    QRectF boundingRect() const override { return QRectF(0,0,20,20); }
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*) override {
        painter->fillRect(QRectF(0,0,20,20), QColor(255,255,0));
    }
};

class TView : public QGraphicsView {
public:
    TView(QWidget* parent) : QGraphicsView(parent) {}
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e) noexcept override {
        QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(e);
        QRectF rc = scene()->sceneRect();
        float s = 1.0f;
        if (rc.width() > viewport()->width()) {
            s = (float)viewport()->width() / rc.width();
            float newHeight = s * rc.height();
            if (newHeight > viewport()->height())
                s = (float)viewport()->height() / rc.height();
        }
        else if (rc.height() > viewport()->height()) {
            s = (float)viewport()->height() / rc.height();
            float newWidth = s * rc.width();
            if (newWidth > viewport()->width())
                s = (float)viewport()->width() / rc.width();
        }
        this->scale(s,s);
    }
};

class TMainWindow : public QWidget  {
    TView* _view = nullptr;
    QGraphicsScene* _scene = nullptr;
public:
    TMainWindow() {
        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        _view = new TView(this);
        _view->setFixedSize(300,400);
        _scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        _view->setScene(_scene);
        _view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
        _view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            TRect* rc = new TRect();
            rc->setPos(i*100,i*100);
            _scene->addItem(rc);
        }        
        layout->addWidget(_view);
    }
};
```

The code contained in TView::resizeEvent you can put in the function and call it when it is required:

- added/removed items to the scene
- changed the view size

Comment: My class is not a subclass of `QGraphicsView` so getting error on line `QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(e);`   as `error: call to non-static member function without an object argument` and `resizeEvent' is a protected member of 'QGraphicsView` So I commented that line and it worked.  I have multiple `view`s , some of the `view`s which has more height are seeing properly but some of the view which are small are almost invisble on screen. I will have to `zoom-in` multiple times to see it.  I have instlled `eventFilter` and in that I am using `resizeEvent`  like `case QEvent::Resize:` and then code.

Comment: I have been told that, this way will work for some of the `view` but not for all the `view`. Try to use logic which uses `ensureVisible`. So now I am confused, how to proceed ?